# How to distinguishe declaration and use of a function?

Tags: c++, syntax, function-calls, function-declaration

I have the following structure in the code:

```
while (x > 0) {
     something;
     aaa::bbb::ccc some_name(
        x,
        y
     );
}
```

I cannot understand what `aaa::bbb::ccc some_name(`. If it is a call of function, why do we need to specify its time `aaa::bbb::ccc`. If it is a declaration of a function, why it is done in while loop and why types of the arguments are not specified?

Comment: Post the actual code.

Comment: :: is a scope resolution operator. bbb an ccc might be some static members or methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify the return type in function calls, so this cannot possibly be a function call.

As Pubby points out, it is very likely an object definition. You define an object called `some_name` of type `aaa::bbb::ccc` and pass `x` and `y` to the constructor.

Comment: @Pubby, I think your comment explains it.

Comment: @Pubby It's defining a local object.  The construction is a side effect of the definition; it ensures that the newly defined object is correctly initialized.

Comment: @JamesKanze The destructor may also have interesting side effects :)

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, it's probably constructing an object `some_name` of type `aaa::bbb::ccc` by calling its two-parameter constructor with arguments `x` and `y`.

The reason why it's done in the loop could be that the object does some useful work in its constructor and/or destructor (it could e.g. be some form of scope guard).

Comment: Of course, if `x` and `y` name types, it _is_ a function declaration.  In simple cases like this, it's usually pretty obvious (and naming conventions help).  In more complicated cases, it can be ambiguous---see "most vexing parse".

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are up to, but the

```
::
```

in C++ is called the `scope-operator` and is used to access `namespaces`, `variables in namespaces` or `static` class-members.

Usually **function**-declarations and definitions appear outside of functions and methods. So your code doesn't make any sense.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b451xz31%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about the scope-operator. And [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html) for declaration vs definition.

Comment: "Usually declarations and definitions appear outside of functions"?  I certainly make extensive use of local variables, and this looks very much like the definition of a local variable.

Comment: @JamesKanze I am sorry, I was not specific enough. I was talking about **function**-declarations and definitions. Thank you for the hint.